# WxPython wxMenu InsertRadioItem issue

Tags: wxpython

```
wxMenuItem = wxMenuSource.InsertRadioItem(order, wx.ID_ANY, test, "")

App.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnPerspective_Click, wxMenuItem)

order += 1
```

I insert radio items procedurally and when I click menu item my program crashs, I don't know what is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this, and there's not really a great "fix".  The problem is that the radio buttons don't get grouped properly when you attempt to add or insert them dynamically.  The best work around I could come up with as this method that I added to my MenuBar class to recreate a Servers menu for me.

```
def setServers(self):
  menu = Menus['Servers']
  while menu.GetMenuItemCount() > 2:
    menu.RemoveItem(menu.FindItemByPosition(2))
  menu.AppendSeparator()
  servers = Config.getValueList('rpcservers', ['hostname', 'port', 'state'])
  for s in servers:
    id = wx.NewId() #@ReservedAssignment
    evtname = 'S%s:%s' % (s['hostname'], s['port'])
    connection = '%s:%s' % (s['hostname'], s['port'])
    menu.Append(id, connection, s['description'], kind = wx.ITEM_RADIO)
    if s['state'] == 'inuse':
      menu.Check(id, True)
```

Some of the code there isn't directly relevant (sorry, quick copy and paste) but the idea here is that the elements that are radio buttons are all at the bottom of this menu.  I remove all of the elements, and a separator, before adding a separator and all of the new radio buttons.  By recreating them in this way I am able to circumvent the bug I was encountering where a newly added radio button wasn't related to its siblings.  Hopefully that helps.  Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardBruner - Glad it helped!  If you've received an answer that solved your problem remember to mark one as accepted so that other users know and can refer back to the question if necessary in the future.